# Sealing Terminals on 150w Garden Transformer

Tags: transformer

I bought a garden transformer to power 2x 12v 50w Halogen lights near the pool.

https://www.bunnings.com.au/hpm-12v-150w-garden-light-transformer_p4396752

Should I be concerned that the terminals on the transformer aren't weather sealed?

What can I seal these with to ensure no water enters the terminal in case of rain, splash etc?

Thanks

Scott

Comment: Personally I’d use an electrical coating even tho it’s only 12v, the go to product would be scotchkote, but it’s is pricey and overkill for this, but a quick amazon search for “electrical coating” yields a few alternatives, such as [this](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B000IC7ZQ2/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_AOv7zbQA95V19) that should be ample and is from a recognized company.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the specs on the link in the question, you'll see they claim that the power supply is rated for outdoors, but not for wet locations.  It will have to be installed indoors or in a suitable enclosure.

Answer (score 0):

12 volts near a freshwater pool or outdoors where saltwater is not present is not much of a danger.  The most likely danger is of burns associated with metal shorting the conductors, like a (jewelry) ring, bracelet, etc.  Pressing a tongue against live 12 volt terminals is exciting—but not dangerous.

If you prefer the terminals be idiot proof (which is a reasonable thing for most people) cover them with silicon caulk, though that inconveniences disconnecting and reconnecting.  The clear flavor of caulk would be my preference so that one can see what is being protected.

Comment: avoid the use of silicon caulk that smells like vinegar or states on the package that acetic acid is released during curing. The acid will corrode metal.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy silicone filled wire nuts (most commonly sold under the Dryconn brand). The silicone is safe for wires and will help protect from corrosion

Comment: Are you sure it's silicone or dielectric grease?

Comment: @EdBeal [Their website says silicone](http://www.kinginnovation.com/products/28/dryconn-extra-large-direct-bury-king-9-dark-blue)

Comment: Ok there is also silicone grease, silicone and RTV are used interchangeably in the construction trade. In the electrical trade it is usually called dielectric grease, this is what I believe Fred_dot_u is saying.

Comment: Took me a few minutes to find the listing information on the ones I have on the shelf. "Moisture and corrosion resistant. Prefilled with 100% non hardening silicone". (I also have a tube of silicone grease it is labeled as dielectric grease).